# React Native apple authentication Login works only once

Tags: ios, react-native

```
import { appleAuth } from '@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication';


const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
      requestedOperation: appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
      requestedScopes: [appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL, appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME],
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('errr', err)
    })
    if (appleAuthRequestResponse.email) {
      const data = {
        email: appleAuthRequestResponse.email,
        provider_id: appleAuthRequestResponse.identityToken,
        provider: 'apple',
        name: appleAuthRequestResponse.fullName.givenName+" "+appleAuthRequestResponse.fullName.familyName,
      }
```

I am using this above code and it works fine only once as the App is added in the iCloud settings then it stopped working. I need email that is compulsory. So if I remove app from iCloud settings then it works again. Why it is happening please check it and provide a solution for this.

Comment: The email address is only provided the first time. You need to cache/store it yourself so that you can provide it on subsequent authentications

Comment: So If I uninstall app and install it again how it will work. @Paulw11

Comment: You store the email along with the `appleUserID` value on your server. You will always get the `appleUserID`https://rossbulat.medium.com/react-native-sign-in-with-apple-75733d3fbc3